# How to implement DjangoModelPermissions for the class based APIView? It throws Queryset error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Scenario:** I have group and permissions, permissions associated to group and that very group is associated to the user. Now I am trying to implement the permissions to the views through **DjangoModelPermissions**

This works fine for the following code lines where **queryset** is implemented;

```
class UpdateCampaignView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]

    queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UpdateCampaignSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        campaign_id = self.request.data.get("id")
        return Campaign.objects.get(id =campaign_id)
```

But I want to implement this to **class based APIView** without queryset keyword something like this:

```
class RetrieveCampaignView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions] #this is what i want to do
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            campaign = Campaign.objects.get(id = request.data.get("id"))
            searializer = GetCampaignSerializer(campaign)
            return Response({"status":True , "payload":searializer.data})
        
        except:
            return Response({"status":False}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

**But This Gives following Error:**

***django rest framework error Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method***

Comment: Why don't you want to specify the `queryset`? I see no reason not to use it in your example.

Comment: Yea, the error says exactly what you have to do but th permission works when you want to access certain instance so implementing it is not reasonable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is an explanation in `DjangoModelPermissions` class;

> This permission can only be applied against view classes that provide
> a `.queryset` attribute.

so, you can't use this permission class without `queryset` attribute. Instead of using this, you can create your own permission class to use with `APIView`. For example you have `permissions.py` like;

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class MyPermission(BasePermission):
    message = "You do not have permission to retrive object"

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.has_perm("app.view_yourmodel"):
            return True
        return False
```

and specify this custom permission class to your view;

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from app.permissions import MyPermission


class RetrieveCampaignView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, MyPermission]

    ...
```

finally, you should find your own permission code from `Permission` model of django and change it with `app.view_yourmodel`. From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions);

> When django.contrib.auth is listed in your INSTALLED_APPS setting, it will ensure that four default permissions – add, change, delete, and view – are created for each Django model defined in one of your installed applications.

so, if you want to find your model permissions;

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from app.models import Campaign


content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Campaign)
perms = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
print([perm.codename for perm in perms])
```

you can visit docs for more information about [custom permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions).

### Updated answer based on comment

> how to make ==> request.user.has_perm('app.view_yourmodel') dynamic
> for code_name else I need to make a whole bunch of MyPermission for
> each view passing for each of has_perm parameter which is code_name.

If you want to use more generic custom permission structure then you can implement your own logic. For example, let's create own view attribute like `perm_slug = "app.model_name"` because we need to know which model user trying to perform action. You must implement this attribute properly for your all view which are going to use `MyPermission` and then parse this attribute in permission class later on get related permission key and check if request user has this permission key.

```
class MyPermission(BasePermission):
    message = "You do not have permission to perform action"
    permission_map = {
        "GET": "{app_label}.view_{model_name}",
        "POST": "{app_label}.add_{model_name}",
        "PUT": "{app_label}.change_{model_name}",
        "PATCH": "{app_label}.change_{model_name}",
        "DELETE": "{app_label}.delete_{model_name}",
    }

    def _get_permission(self, method, perm_slug):
        app, model = perm_slug.split(".")
        if method not in self.permission_map:
            raise MethodNotAllowed(method)
        perm = self.permission_map.get(method).format(app_label=app, model_name=model)
        return perm

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        perm = self._get_permission(
            method=request.method, perm_slug=view.perm_slug
        )
        if request.user.has_perm(perm):
            return True
        return False
```

and modify your view like;

```
class RetrieveCampaignView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, MyPermission]
    perm_slug = "app.campaign"

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @uedemir . I am upvoting this answer, insightful . Also , can you elaborate on how to make  ==> request.user.has_perm('app.view_yourmodel')   dynamic for code_name else I need to make a whole bunch of MyPermission for each view passing for each of has_perm parameter which is code_name. Is there a better way for that such as making decorator may be , would be thankful if you help me sort this !

Comment: this looks good :) , Can't wait to implement. I guess it works fine, good code . Thanks for the effort.

Comment: really great answer, i wish DRF would actually support this kind of behavior for the APIView instead.